# How to insert on a newline, pushing everything after the cursor down with it

Tags: insert-mode, cursor

Say my cursor is `[]`:

```
(A very intelligent turtle[)]
```

I'd like to issue something like `o` that would put me in insert mode here:

```
(A very intelligent turtle
[)]
```

I'm using spacemacs.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Doesn't `i` followed by "Enter" do exactly what you described?

Comment: Thank you! Yes it does, but I was wondering if there was a one-key alternative, or variation of `o` that does that?

Comment: You can always create your own keybindings... Assuming you want `<CR>` (in Normal mode) for that command, and that you'd like to stay in Normal mode at the end, you can use `nnoremap <CR> i<CR><Esc>`.

Comment: Okay, I guess your answer is the simplest though. If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this task with `i` (to enter Insert mode) followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which will break the line taking the part starting at the character under the cursor to the next line. This sequence will leave you in Insert mode.

If you'd like to repeat that for many lines, you can use `i`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, to simply break the line and return to Normal mode. At that point, you can use the [`.`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#.) command to repeat that insertion that is just breaking the line the way you want. So you can keep moving to the next position where you want to break the line and press `.` to break it. If you're using a search (for example, looking for a `)` at the end of the line, with `/)$`), you can repeat the search too with `n`, so you can keep hitting `n.n.n.` etc. to find the next match and break the line, possibly skipping a break by just pressing `n`s more than once.

If this is an action you repeat often and would like an even shorter sequence than `i`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you can create a mapping for it. For example:

```
:nnoremap <CR> i<CR>
```

This maps the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in Normal mode, and does the `i`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> action that breaks the line and leaves you in Insert mode.

If you want to end back in Normal mode, and prefer a different key for mapping, say <kbd>,</kbd>, then use something like:

```
:nnoremap , i<CR><Esc>
```

Hopefully these examples will be helpful, you can adapt them to whatever makes the most sense for your specific use case.